# How can I get single item's id in Ant Design table column rendering

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, rendering, ant-design-pro

Here **cartItems** is the array I passed as a datasource!

```
<Table
        style={{ marginTop: '2rem' }}
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={cartItems}
     />
```

How can I get single item in my **cartItems** array inside the **render()** method ?
I just want to extract the id & want to pass it inside deleteFromCart(id).

```
  const columns = [
{ title: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', key: 'name' },
{ title: 'Quantity', dataIndex: 'quantity', key: 'quantity' },
{ title: '$ Unit Price', dataIndex: 'price', key: 'price' },
{ title: '$ Total Price', dataIndex: 'totalPrice', key: 'totalPrice' },
{
  title: 'cartItem',
  dataIndex: 'cartItem',
  key: 'cartItem',
  render: (cartItem) => (
    <a
      style={{ color: 'red' }}
      onClick={(cartItem) => {
        deleteFromCart(cartItem.id)
        console.log('delete')
      }}
    >
      Remove
    </a>
  ),
},
```

]

Im unable to extract the id..Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument (record) is the particular record inside the array!

```
render: (item,record) => (    //second argument is the item
        <a
          style={{ color: 'red' }}
          onClick={(e) => {
            deleteFromCart(record.id)
          }}
        >
          Remove
        </a>
      ),
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

`onClick` event gives you `event` object and not the `record` of table. In your case, since the variable name is same, `cartItem` from `render` is being shadowed by `cartItem` from `onClick handler` function

```
{
  title: 'cartItem',
  dataIndex: 'cartItem',
  key: 'cartItem',
  render: (cartItem) => (
    <a
      style={{ color: 'red' }}
      onClick={(e) => { // remove cartItem from here
        deleteFromCart(cartItem.id)
        console.log('delete')
      }}
    >
      Remove
    </a>
  ),
}
```